# Quotient Space (W-Affine Subspaces) "Proof" Verification.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $(V, K)$ be a vector space
>   and $W ⊂ V$ a subspace. A subset $S ⊂ V$ is called a $W$-affine subspace of $V$
>   if the following holds
>   $∀s, s ∈ S, s − s ∈ W$ and $∀s ∈ S, ∀w ∈ W, s + w ∈ S$.
>
> 1. Let S and T be W-affine subspace of V and c ∈ K. Define
>
> $$S + T = \lbrace s + t \space | \space s ∈ S, t ∈ T\rbrace$$
>
> $$cT =
> \begin{cases} 
> \lbrace ct \space | \space t ∈ T\rbrace \space \text{if} \space c= 0\\
> W \space \text{if} \space c = 0.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $S+T$ and $cT$ are again $W$-affine subspaces of $V$.
>
> 2. Show that the above operations turn the set of all $W$-affine subspaces
>      of $V$ into a vector space that we will denote by the symbol $V/W$ and
>      we call it the quotient space. Note that vectors in the quotient space
>      are $W$-affine subsets of $V$.
> 3. Show that if $v ∈ V$ then $v + W = \lbrace v + w \space|\space w ∈ W\rbrace$ is a $W$-affine subspace of $V$. Furthermore, show that for any $W$-affine subspace $S ∈ V/W$ there exists a $v ∈ V$ such that $S = v + W$.

Hello there. I know this question is quite long, but the parts are all related, so just bear with me please. I attempted parts $1$ and $2$, but I was not sure about these attempts and I completely do not know how to approach number $3$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**My attempts:**

1. Since $S$ and $T$ are $W$-affine subspaces (by definition)

$s-s' \in W \space \forall \space s, s' \in S, t-t' \in W \space \forall \space t, t' \in T$

Therefore,

$s-s' \in W \implies s-s'=w_1\in W$ and $t-t' \in W \implies t-t'=w_2 \in W$

By definition of $S + T$;

$$S + T = \underbrace{(s - s')}_{\in \space S} + \underbrace{(t - t')}_{\in \space T}\\
= (s - s') + (t - t') = w_1 + w_2\\
=(s + t) - (s' + t') = w_1 + w_2$$

Since $W$ is a subspace, $w_1 + w_2 \in W$,

$$\implies S + T = (s + t) - (s' + t') \in W$$

Also, since $S$ and $T$ are $W$-affine subspaces, $s + w_1 \in S$ and $t + w_2 \in T$
$$\therefore S + T = \underbrace{(s + w_1)}_{\in \space S} + \underbrace{(t + w_2)}_{\in \space T}\\
=(s + t) + \underbrace{(w_1 + w_2)}_{\text{any}\space w \space \in \space W}$$
$$\implies S + T = (s + t) + w$$

And therefore, $S + T$ is again a $W$-affine subspace of $V$.

Similar process for $cT$ ending up with:
$$cT =c(t - t') \in W, \text{and}\space cT = ct + w$$

2. I defined addition and scalar multiplication as follows 
   $$+ : S + T = (s + t) + (t + w) = (s + t) + w$$
   $$\cdot : cT = c(t + w) = (ct) + w$$
   and then just showed (using those definitions) that they satisfy the properties of a vector space: commutative, associative, additive identity, additive inverse, multiplicative inverse, distributivity of $\cdot$ over $+$ and addition distribution property and thus $V/W$ forms a vector space.
3. Was thinking it'd somehow look like my approach for number $1$?? Not entirely sure how to approach it.

Thanks for taking the time to read/help me :)

Answer (score 0):

1.- The proof goes as follows (see that for this part you don't need them to be subspaces):

Let $s_1+t_1$ and $s_2+t_2$ arbitrary elements in $S+T$. Then $(s_1+t_1)-(s_2+t_2) = (s_1-s_2)+(t_1-t_2)$. Since both sets are $W$-affine there exist $w_s$ and $w_t \in W$ such that $s_1-s_2=w_s$ and $t_1-t_2=w_t$. Since $W$ is a subspace, this implies that $(s_1+t_1)-(s_2+t_2)\in W$, hence $S+T$ is a $W$-affine.

2.- With 1 you already defined both operations, after this you should verify the distributivity, find the inverses and the identity sets. Hint: $W$ itself is $W$-affine.

Edit: Observe that $S+W=S$ for every $W$-affine set $S$. So this is your zero vector in $V/W$. For the inverse, you can show that $S+S=W$ (since $S$ is a subspace this is equivalent to taking $(s+W)+((-s)+W)=W$).

3.- I'll leave the first part to you. For the second part one contention follows immediately from the definition. For the other see that $S\subseteq s+W$ for any $s\in S$. Show it doesn't matter which $s$ you choose ($s+W=s'+W$).

Comment: Firstly thank you. Okay I understand the corrections to $1$ - the way you suggested is indeed more logical than what I did, doing $cT$ now. For $2$ does that mean I should use the definitions given in part $1$ when verifying distributivity, finding the inverses and the identities? Cause I verified the distributivity and found the inverse and identity with the definitions I put forward.

Comment: a) You should also prove the other condition ($s+w\in S$), in my post I only proved the first one. b) Well, I think that's why the first part of the exercise is to define a sum and a scalar multiplication ;) (also I think what you did isn't right, I don't think you're proving what you intend to).

Comment: Okay, so would the way how I proved the second part of $1$ be correct, or is that also incorrect?? I was pretty convinced that what I did was incorrect, I was sort of cheating, cause I was entirely unsure of how to start..

Comment: The idea is right, but again I think you could do it more efficiently. How about: Let $s+t$ be in $S+T$, then for any $w$ we have $(s+t)+w = s+(t+w) = s+t'$ since T is $W$-affine. This element clearly is in $S+T$. Also, be careful with notation! Writing things like $S+T = s+t +...$ doesn't make sense, on one side you have a set and on the other elements of a set.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is much better. & I did realize that, but I couldnt conceive a nicer way of writing it. Okay so for $cT$ this is what I came up with. When $c=0$, $cT$ is $W \in W$ so that case is ok. If $c \ne 0$ then for any arbitrary $t, t' \in T$, $ct - ct' = c(t-t') \in W$ since $T$ is $W$-affine, then $\exists w_t$ such that $t-t'=w_t$ and since $W$ is a subspace $\implies ct - ct' \in W$.

Comment: For the second one, if $c=0$, $cT$ is $W$. Take an arbitrary $w \in W$, $\implies t=0$ and therefore $t+w=0+w \in T$. If $c\ne 0$, let $t \in T$, since $T$ is $W$-affine, for any arbitrary $w$, $t+w \in T$, $\implies c(t+w) = ct' \in T$.

Comment: ****CORRECTION: For the additive inverse it would be $S + T$ where $T = 0$ which $\implies S + T = \lbrace s + 0 | s \in S, 0 \in T \rbrace = S$. For the additive inverse it would be $S + T$ where $T = -s$ which $\implies S + T = \lbrace s + (-s) | s \in S, -s \in T \rbrace = 0_{V/W}$. And for the multiplicative inverse, $c = 1$ then, $1S=\lbrace 1S | s \in S \rbrace = S$.

Comment: Okay, so what I have would be incorrect with T? It strictly has to be W?

Comment: & I just want to make sure I am following, you are saying that W is the additive identity since it is the zero vector in V/W? But shouldnt the zero vector added to S return S? I think I get the inverse one.

Comment: You're right, it's a typo.

Comment: Okay, finally for number $3$. This is what I managed to scrape up. Let $v, v'$ be arbitrary elements in $V$. Then, $(v + w) - (v' + w') = (v - v') + (w - w')$ which $\implies v - v' = w' - w \in W$. The $v + w \in V$ giving me trouble now, I wanna say that by definition this is true. Which will prove that $v + W$ is $W$-affine.